# Вывод текстового массива в label

Tags: c#, winforms

Имеется данный код:

```
for (int item = 0; item < Mass.Length; item++)
{
     if (Mass[item].Remove(0, Mass[item].Length - 2) == "ed"
         || Mass[item].Remove(0, Mass[item].Length - 2) == "ED")
     {
          Mass[item] = Mass[item].Remove(Mass[item].Length - 2, 2) + "ing";
     }
     label3.Text = Convert.ToString(Mass[item]);
}
```

При выполнении на поле выводится только последняя выполненная операция. Что изменить, что бы выводилось все элементы массива?
Например: Extand mixed rule pasted -> Extand mixing rule pasting

Comment: Добавьте "+" в последнюю строчку: label3.Text += Convert.ToString(Mass[item]);

Comment: Выводит ошибку: https://goo.gl/tNEiZe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы на каждой итерации цикла переприсваиваете значение текста в лейбле. Вынесите установку за цикл:

```
for (int item = 0; item < Mass.Length; item++)
{
    if (Mass[item].Remove(0, Mass[item].Length - 2) == "ed"
        || Mass[item].Remove(0, Mass[item].Length - 2) == "ED")
    {
         Mass[item] = Mass[item].Remove(Mass[item].Length - 2, 2) + "ing";
    }
}

// склеиваем слова в строчку, слова будут разделены пробелом
label3.Text = string.Join(" ", Mass);
```

Более того, ваша проверка на окончание слов может быть упрощена:

```
for (int item = 0; item < Mass.Length; item++)
{
    if (Mass[item].EndsWith("ed", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
         Mass[item] = Mass[item].Remove(Mass[item].Length - 2, 2) + "ing";
    }
}

// склеиваем слова в строчку, слова будут разделены пробелом
label3.Text = string.Join(" ", Mass);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Как теперь убрать эту часть: https://goo.gl/0AqJp4 ?

Comment: @Дмитрий: Это уже следующий вопрос, задавайте его отдельно. С этим всё ясно?

Comment: Да. Тут всё понятно

Comment: @Дмитрий можете тогда пометить как верный (галочка рядом с ответом).